# XSLT / conditional for-each with same parent (uncle) node value

Tags: xslt, foreach

I need some help understanding how I can select only certain nodes having same parent (or uncle) element value.  My XML looks like this

```
<shipment>
  <goodslines>
    <goodsline>
        <position>1</position>
        <packagenumbers>
            <packagenumber>123</packagenumber>
        </packagenumbers>
    </goodsline>
    <goodsline>
        <position>1</position>
        <packagenumbers>
            <packagenumber>456</packagenumbers>
        </packagenumbers>
    </goodsline>
    <goodsline>
        <position>2</position>
        <packagenumbers>
            <packagenumber>789</packagenumbers>
        </packagenumbers>
    </goodsline>
  </goodslines>
</shipment>
```

and the desired output would be:

```
123,456
789
```

So I would need to do for-each to "packagenumber" - level so, that it would take in consideration the "position" - element from upper level

The XSL might be something like this?

```
        <xsl:for-each select="shipment/goodslines/goodsline[some condition here?]/packagenumbers/packagenumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

If your xml always has the same structure you can use this:

```
<xsl:template match="goodsline[position = preceding-sibling::goodsline[1]/position]">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="packagenumbers/packagenumber"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="goodsline">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="packagenumbers/packagenumber"/>
</xsl:template>
```

More specific templates (the one with the condition) will always hit first and have higher priority. There is probably another simple solution with for-each-group.

Comment: This is not a good method - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: This article is saying that this is inefficient because it is comparing the node with EVERY previous node. I get your point, but mine is just looking at the first preceding node, which is working in case of his xml. @michael.hor257k
I did not have the time to read all though. But I am familiar with the xsl 1.0 for-each-group workaround.